# Custom ListView doesn't display image in Second Activity when item clicked on

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I have put together a custom ListView, with images and text in a list.
I have then created a second activity to display the image in a larger format, when clicked on in the list.

Although I have put together all the correct-looking code (no errors etc),
the Intent is not displaying the larger image (images are all in the same drawable folder - only size set in the ImageViews gives different ouput.
The App displays the image and text in the ListView but no image shows up in the `single_list_item_view` screen (it goes to the second screen OK when a 
sinle row is clicked).

Here's my code:

**MainActivity.java**:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView list;
    String[] web = {
        "Google Plus",
            "Twitter",
            "Windows",
            "Bing",
            "Itunes",
            "Wordpress",
            "Drupal"
    } ;
    Integer[] imageId = {
            R.drawable.image1,
            R.drawable.image2,
            R.drawable.image3,
            R.drawable.image4,
            R.drawable.image5,
            R.drawable.image6,
            R.drawable.image7


    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        CustomList adapter = new
                CustomList(MainActivity.this, web, imageId);
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
                list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {

                        ImageView imgview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);
                        int images = imgview.getId();
                        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " +web[+ position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
                        i.putExtra("zurag", images);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });




    }

}
```

**CustomList.java:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

private final Activity context;
private final String[] web;
private final Integer[] imageId;
public CustomList(Activity context,
String[] web, Integer[] imageId) {
super(context, R.layout.list_single, web);
this.context = context;
this.web = web;
this.imageId = imageId;

}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);
TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
txtTitle.setText(web[position]);

imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
return rowView;
}
}
```

**SingleListItem.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class SingleListItem extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item_view);

        ImageView images = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        int pic =i.getIntExtra("zurag", 0);
        images.setImageResource(pic);

    }
}
```

**list_single.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TableRow>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="25dip"
            android:layout_height="70dp" />

</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

single_list_item_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="480dp"
        android:layout_height="344dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="145dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
       android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

HERE IS THE MISSING SingleListItem Class:

Comment: where is your code for `SingleListItem` class

Comment: I'm confused, does it or does it not show your image in your "second activity"?

Comment: It's already been posten @KaranMer

Comment: Line `int images = imgview.getId();` is incorrect. it retrieves the id of imageview not the resource of an image. U need to pass the resource of an image.

Answer (score 1):

> Custom ListView doesn't display image in Second Activity when item
>   clicked on

`imgview.getId();` return `id` of `ImageView` instead of image drawable id which is used as `ImageView` `src`.

Use `getAdapter().getItem` or `imageId[position]` to get id of clicked row Drawable :

```
 int images = parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
```

Now send `images` with Intent in next Activity

EDIT:

Add `getItem` method in `CustomList` class:

```
@Override
public int  getItem(int position) {
    return imageId[position];
}
```

Comment: Hi! When I substituted your line of code, I receive the error "cannot convert from Obj to Int.."??

Comment: @user1641906 need to override getItem method in adapter because by default getItem method return object

Comment: So what should the code look like - I'm confused now?

Comment: @user1641906: see my answer let me know if still have issue

Answer (score 0):

pass below id in your intent Extra. **imageId[position]** and it should work.

basically this line

`i.putExtra("zurag", images);`

will become

`i.putExtra("zurag", imageId[position]);`

you are passing resource id of your image view, while you should have passed resource ID of your drawable/image file.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
  @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {

                    ImageView imgview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);
                    int images = position;
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " +web[+ position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
                    i.putExtra("zurag", images);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

**imgview.getId()** will give you the image view ID and not the image you have pointed.

try this,

In the getview of ur CustomList add a line like this,

imageView.setTag(imageId[position]).

And in the List Click Listener get the ID like this,

**imgview.getTag()** and give it to the Intent object

**i.putExtra("zurag", imgview.getTag());**

Answer (score 0):

You can user below code for MainActivity.

```
@Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                ImageView imgview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);
                int images = position;
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
                i.putExtra("zurag", position);
                startActivity(i);
            }
```

Now you can get images in SingleListItem Activity using below code.

```
   public class SingleListItem extends Activity{

    Integer[] imageId = {
        R.drawable.image1,
        R.drawable.image2,
        R.drawable.image3,
        R.drawable.image4,
        R.drawable.image5,
        R.drawable.image6,
        R.drawable.image7
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item_view);

    ImageView images = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    int pic =i.getIntExtra("zurag", 0);
    images.setImageResource(imageId[pic]);

}
```

}

Comment: Tried your code - but says in last line of SingleListItem that it can't use the static field of MainActivity..

Comment: you can use imageId array in this activity and second way is create one more class like constant and put image array on that class. now use my code.